# flask Sqlalchemy One to Many getting parent attributes

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Im trying to get the Pet owner or persons name

```
class Person(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = db.Column(db.String(20))
        pets = db.relationship('Pet', backref='owner', lazy='dynamic')


class Pet(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20))
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('person.id'))
```

I want to query the pets and after i select a pet i want to get pet owner names

```
pets = Pet.query.all()
for pet in pets:
    print pet.owner_id
```

will give the owner id but i want to owner name

Comment: You should read the SQLAlchemy ORM tutorial. Working with relationships in this way are covered there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pets = db.session.query(Pet, Person.name).join(Person)

for pet, person_name in pets:
    print pet.name, person_name
```

Using that type of querying we force SQLAlchemy to use Mapping of `pet` table to `Pet` object and get `Person`'s name as second item in select. Of course you can use something like that:

```
pets = db.session.query(Pet, Person).join(Person)
```

then you'll be able to use it in this way:

```
for pet, person in pets:
    print pet.name, person.name
```

so have reference to a person as object of `Person` class. But first option is more preferable because it's faster, just because of getting person's name only.

Comment: Thank you very much this. It worked.  can you  me a favor and link me  to docs so I can learn.

Comment: Sure, here is about querying: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html , but maybe I will explain more in my answer.