# Is it possible to have SQL Alchemy database models point to attributes of a different model, so that when one model's data changes, so does the other?

Tags: python, database, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm making a very simple warehouse management system, and I'd like for users to be able to create templates for items. The template will show up on a list, and then can individually be used to create instances of an item that will also gain a quantity and warehouse attribute.

The goal is, if one of the item templates gets modified to specify a different size or price, the size or price attributes of the actual item instance gets changed as well.

Here is my code in case that helps you visualize what I'm trying to do. I'm not sure if this is possible or if there is a different solution I should consider. It's my first time working with Flask SQLAlchemy.

````
class ItemTemplate(db.model):

    """This template will simply store the information related to an item type.
    Individual items that will be associated with the warehouse they're stored in
    will inherit this information from the item templates."""

    _id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(15), unique=True, nullable=False)
    price = db.column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    cost = db.column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    size = db.column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    lowThreshold = db.column(db.Integer, nullable=False)


# Actual items
class Item(db.model):

    """This template will be used to represent the actual items that are associated with a warehouse."""

    _id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    quantity = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    """Here I want the Item attributes to be able to just point to attributes from the ItemTemplate class.
    
    ItemTemplate(name='tape') <--- will be a template with the information for tape.
    Item(name='tape') <--- will be an actually instance of tape that should inherit all the attributes from the tape template.
    
    I want these attributes to be like pointers so that if the tape template has its name changed, for instance, to
    'scotch tape', all the Item instances that point to the tape template will have their names changed."""


# Warehouse
class Warehouse(db.model):

    _id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(15), unique=True, nullable=False)
    capacity = db.Column(db.column(db.Integer, nullable=False))
    items = db.relationship("Item", backref="warehouse", lazy=True)```
````

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you just declare a One-Many relationship between `ItemTemplate` and `Item`, that one template will be used for many items.

#### Define Model

Just try to declare their relationship like this

```py
class ItemTemplate(db.model):
    _id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    ... # Other attribute

    instances = db.relationship('item', backref='item_template', lazy=True)


class Item(db.model):
    _id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    quantity = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    item_template_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('item_template._id'), nullable=False)
```

Docs for more information about relationship:
https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/#one-to-many-relationships

#### Query

Next time querying, just join two tables and you can have your `ItemTemplate.name`

```py
items_qr = db.session.query(Item, ItemTemplate.name).join(ItemTemplate)

for item, item_name in items_qr:
    print(item.id, item_name)
```

SQLAlchemy Doc for `query.join()`: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.join

#### Some relative SO questions may help

- [flask Sqlalchemy One to Many getting parent attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39822087/flask-sqlalchemy-one-to-many-getting-parent-attributes)
- [One-to-many Flask | SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25375179/one-to-many-flask-sqlalchemy)